# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR: column is of type integer[] but default expression is of type integer Rails 4.1.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, postgresql-9.1

I am using Rails 4.1.1 and pg (0.17.1) gem I having error while running the migration

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "page_ids" is of type integer[] but default expression is of type integer

here is my migration code

```
class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
        create_table :pages do |t|
            t.string     :name
            t.integer    :page_ids,     array: true, null: false, default: '{}'
            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end
```

the array: true not working

Comment: I have found the fix of this issue 
t.integer    :page_ids,     array: true, null: false, default: []
not to use '{}' this for string not for integer

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
t.integer    :page_ids,     array: true, null: false, default: []
```